# Fade an image's bottom edge to white in GIMP? Current method results in far too "harsh" a gradient

Tags: gimp, gradient

I have a series of photos that I'd like to create the effect of them fading to white on the bottom edge in gimp.

I have this working very nicely in CSS already with linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%).

When I try to create a similar effect in GIMP, I end up with a gradient that is far too harsh - nowhere near as smooth/subtle as the CSS effect.

Steps:

1. load photo
2. create new white background layer
3. select photo layer
4. add layer mask
5. set bg/fg colour to white/black
6. draw gradient
7. disappointment

What am I doing wrong?

What I get with CSS(left), and Gimp (right):

[image: CSS][image: Gimp]

Thanks, I can't tell you how much time I've lost to this today!

Comment: Your gradient is too short. Make it longer by drawing the gradient from the bottom to the top of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your technique is OK, using it I get this:

[image]

While my layer stack looks like this:

[image]

So it all depends what the gradient on the mask looks like (add screenshot to you question?). From your picture it looks like you applied the gradient on a short distance;  in mine the gradient is made using the `FG to BG (RGB)` gradient, clicking on the bottom edge, and then dragging all the way up to the top edge.

By the way, once you have a linear gradient in the mask, you can adjust the fade using the regular "Colors" tools on the mask: Brightness/Contrast,  Levels, and Curves. Brightness/Contrast and Levels.

Edit: since 2.10, you can also click around the middle of the gradient segment. This makes the "midpoint" appear, and you can then use move the midpoint to change the gradient:

[image]

Comment: It's odd, the standard gradient I draw looks nothing like the one you've drawn unless I edit the curve significantly.

Comment: Are you using 2.10 and an image in "Linear light"?

Comment: 2.10 yes, not sure what the other part of your question means, but I've not intentionally changed anything from a clean install.

Comment: In 2.10, with high-precision images (more than 8-bit per channel) you can work in perceptual (ie, gamma-corrected, like in 8-bit) or linear light (no correction).